# Calculate expected goals from given odds

Tags: probability, gambling

I'm trying to work out a formula to calculate the expected number of goals in a soccer match, using only odds data provided by a bookmaker:

```
> Home team: 3.4 (29.4%)
> Away Team: 2.3 (43.4%)
> Draw: 3.65 (27.3%)
> 
> Over 2.5 goals: 1.88 (53.1%)
> Under 2.5 goals: 2.1 (47.6%)
```

I have put these numbers into an online calculator, and gotten the following results:

```
> Average home goals: 1.25
> Average away goals: 1.574
> Average total goals: 2.824
```

I can't understand how this is calculated though - any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Which online calculator have you used?

Comment: https://annabet.com/en/poissoned/

Comment: I haven´t found the applet where I can input your proposed values. Please be more specific.